# Doing research on Google Matrix and PageRank algorithm

Tags: computer-science, education

I'm doing research on Google Matrix and PageRank algorithm. In a paper, there are terms that I'm unaware of, such as stationary distribution, stochastic matrix, convex combination, markov matrix, power method, perturbation bounds... If I want to know more about there, which concept of mathematics is it?

Comment: Stationary distribution, stochastic matrix, Markov property: Markov chains

Answer (score 1):

These are related to random walks or generally stochastic processes.
A good book about it for the beginning: [Rick Durrett - Essentials of Stochastic Processes](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf)